# Flatten a list in R based on conditions

Tags: r, list, flatten

I want to figure out how to flatten a nested list based on certain conditions. Here is an example list -

```
example_list <- list(list1 = list(data = mtcars, char = c("a","b")),
                     num = c(1:3),
                     mat = matrix(1:10),
                     list2 = list(c = "c",d = "d"),
                     list3 = list(1, 2))
```

I want to flatten the elements of this list if (1) the class of the element is not a data.frame/matrix/character/numeric or (2) if the name of the element is not "list2". The flattened list should therefore contain these elements - data, char, num, mat, list2, 1, 2.

The expected output should be -

```
output <- list(data = mtcars, 
               char = c("a","b"),
               num = c(1:3),
               mat = matrix(1:10),
               list2 = list(c = "c", d = "d"),
               1,2)
```

P.S.: It would be great if there is a `rrapply` based solution to this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me where the name `list1` comes from in `output`, could it be that the names `list1` and `list2` have been mixed up?

Comment: @JorisC. Indeed. That was a typo. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the names `list1` and `list2` in `example_list` should be switched, with `rrapply()` we could do:

```r
## flatten list based on condition(s)
output <- rrapply(
  example_list,
  how = "flatten",
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "list1" || is.data.frame(x) || is.character(x) || is.numeric(x),
)

str(output, list.len = 7)

#> List of 7
#>  $ data :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>   ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. [list output truncated]
#>  $ char : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
#>  $ num  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>  $ mat  : int [1:10, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ list1:List of 2
#>   ..$ c: chr "c"
#>   ..$ d: chr "d"
#>  $ 1    : num 1
#>  $ 2    : num 2
```

**Explanation**

- Use `how = "flatten"` to return the result as a flattened list
- We set `classes = c("list", "ANY")` to evaluate (intermediate) `list` elements as well, which allows us to avoid flattening the `list1` element.
- The `condition` function says which elements should be evaluated, and since `f` is unspecified, the evaluated elements are just returned as is. In particular, we check if an element is named `"list1"` or is a data.frame, character or numeric object, in which case it is returned as is. Otherwise, `rrapply()` will recurse deeper into the element (e.g. for `list2` and `list3`).

**Data**

```r
## switch names list1 and list2
example_list <- list(
  list2 = list(data = mtcars, char = c("a","b")),
  num = c(1:3),
  mat = matrix(1:10),
  list1 = list(c = "c", d = "d"),
  list3 = list(1, 2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. There was a typo in my question. But this is the answer I was looking for.